# ADFS Native Application Access Token Missing Claims

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, adfs

I am trying to authenticate WPF application that communicates with my ASP.NET MVC API using ADFS. I've managed to get the access token and use it to properly pass the `Authorize` attribute, but I've noticed that the access token lacks some crucial claims (for example `upn`) that I would like to use for unique user identification in API's controllers. I've also noticed that `IdToken` string and `UserInfo` object are available alongside the `AccessToken` string in the `AuthenticationResult` object after a successful authentication and that they both contain the proper `upn` value.

The problem is that I cannot use the `IdToken` with the authorization header as I get the `Unauthorized` response error.

I am using the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` in my client app and the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` library in the API.

Client code:

```
var authRes = await authCtx.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceAddress, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)); //resourceAddress equals the API url
```

API code:

```
       app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
           new Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
           {
               MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],  //standard ADFS metadata endpoint
               TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
               {
                   ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"] // API url
               }, 
           });
```

There is also a claim rule configured for the UPN value on the ADFS server:

[UPN rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw1fa.png)